# find somewhere using the name and coordinate leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geocoding

I have two questions:

1.
   I'm working with leaflet map, and I add a search bar.
   I have a table that contains the names of high schools and their 
   geographical coordinates.

I would like to type in the search bar the name of a high school that I 
   place a marker in this place with information about the school.
   How can I do that?

2.
  I would also like to place colors on high schools according to a table 
  provided to indicate me an alert on a high school?

[0 - 10] : red 
  [11 - 20] : orange 
  [21 - 30] : green

//This is my searsh script

```
var searchControl = L.esri.Geocoding.geosearch().addTo(oMap);

    var results = L.layerGroup().addTo(oMap);

    searchControl.on('results', function (data) {
        results.clearLayers();
        for (var i = data.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            results.addLayer(L.marker(data.results[i].latlng));
        }
    });
```

this is my array:

```
var listEcole = [
  ['rhone','45.75','4.85'],
  ['Cité Scolaire ELIE VIGNAL','45.79264','4.85323'],
  ['Collège et Lycée Elie Vignal','45.783127','4.8355978'],
  ['bangkok','13.69214','100.75072'],
  ['new-york','40.64557','-73.78495'],
  ['paris','49.0142','2.54188']
];
```

Comment: could you show more code to see what you have achieved so far ? Besides, you talk about alert information but it does not appear in your array `listEcole`. Where does this info come from ?

Comment: j'ai pas écris beaucoup de code pour cette partie,
normalement avec ce code j'arrive à rechercher n'importe quel pays ou ville... et il me localise le pays ou la ville.
maintenant moi je voudrais rechercher un lycée qui sera donné en tableau comme indiqué dans le tableau  listEcole

Comment: and for the alert it's just an explanation because I want to put colors on each high school but according to a table of value that will be provided to me that's why I give an example with these ranges of values.
but we can imagine it as follows:

function getColor (d) {
   return d> 1000? '# 800026':
          d> 500? '# BD0026':
          d> 200? '# E31A1C':
          d> 100? '# FC4E2A':
          d> 50? '# FD8D3C':
          d> 20? '# FEB24C':
          d> 10? '# FED976':
                     '# FFEDA0';
}